# LaTeX Error: Command `\circledS' already defined. mathdesign conflict with amssymb

Tags: mathdesign, amssymb

This MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\begin{document}
t
\end{document}
```

gives the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Command `\circledS' already defined.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
l.160 ...mbol{\circledS}     {\mathord}{AMSa}{"73}
```

I changed to `{mathdesign}` and now I am getting this error in all my files, which uses the package `amssymb`

Is there a trick to make both of these package works in the same file?

TL 2015

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
mathdesign.sty    2013/08/29 v2.31 Math Design Project
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
   mdbch.cfg
   mdbch.sty    2013/08/29 v2.31 bitstream bitstream charter + mdbch (Math Desi
gn Project)
  mdfont.def    2013/08/29 v2.31 (Math Design Project)
mdsffont.def    2013/08/29 v2.31 (Math Design Project)
mdttfont.def    2013/08/29 v2.31 (Math Design Project)
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
ot1mdbch.fd    2013/08/29 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for OT1/mdbch.
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
 t1mdbch.fd    2013/08/29 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for T1/mdbch.
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
  mdacmr.fd    
  mdbcmr.fd
```

Comment: mathdesign explictly in the first line of its documentation says it replicates all the standard and ams fonts with its own set, so what would it mean to have amssymb and mathdesign at the same time, do you want \approxeq to be the ams one or the mathdesign one?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you prefer `\circledS` from `amssymb`, the following will be enough:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\let\circledS\undefined % here - PS
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\begin{document}
t
\end{document}
```